# Suppress Page Numbers in classicthesis (chapterpagestyle)

Tags: koma-script, page-numbering, classicthesis

I am using the *classicthesis* style from [André Miede's Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/amiede/classicthesis/wiki/Home).

I would like to suppress page numbering on the first page of each chapter.

Using `\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{empty}` in the preamble doesn't appear to have any effect.

Please see MWE below:

```
\documentclass[%
  twoside,%
  openright,%
  numbers=noenddot,%
  headinclude,%
  footinclude,%
  cleardoublepage=empty,%
  paper=a4,%
  fontsize=11pt%
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{classicthesis}

\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{empty}

\begin{document}

  \chapter{Chapter One}

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam nisl augue,
  hendrerit non convallis nec, finibus et nisl. Duis purus nulla, congue placerat
  nisi eget, lacinia maximus nisi. Donec euismod magna neque, ac blandit sem
  consectetur vitae. Proin cursus odio eros, vel eleifend nisl commodo ac.
  Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `classicthesis` package deliberately designs the first page of a chapter to have page number in the right-outer foot position. In particular, in [`classicthesis.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis/classicthesis.sty), we find this line:

```
\ofoot[\small\pagemark]{}% only for plain.scrheadings page style (first page of a chapter)
```

So all we need to do is to overwrite this with `\ofoot[]{}`.

```
\documentclass[%
  twoside,%
  openright,%
  numbers=noenddot,%
  headinclude,%
  footinclude,%
  cleardoublepage=empty,%
  paper=a4,%
  fontsize=11pt%
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{classicthesis}

\ofoot[]{}% <- added here

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

  \chapter{Chapter One}

  \blindtext[10]

\end{document}
```

[image: page number suppressed]